# How do you search a sheet using gspread for an item matching multiple criteria?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I'm trying to develop a Python script to search a sheet for a particular row, matching multiple criteria. I'll start with a sample scenario, a fruits menu in Google Sheets. See screenshot below. Note, this example might or might not reflect actual prices.

In `gspread`, I would normally use the `find` function to search for a particular item (e.g. `cell = worksheet.find("Apple")`) and from that I can find out which row the item is located in. However, this might only find the row for the first "Apple" entry that appears. In the sample below, it'll find the "green apple" and its corresponding row - Row 2.

What if I'm interested in the row number of a fruit matching a certain criteria? For example, `Apple, Red`, which is located in Row 6. How do I search a sheet using `gspread` (`find` function) to find a particular row of something matching 2 or more criteria? In the example, I want to return the row number containing the red apple (Row 6), which seems to appear after the first apple entry (green apple).

[image: Fruits Menu]

**EDIT:**

- Solved / Answered (Code Snippet Below)
- Thanks @Tanaike

```
# OUTPUT: Code below updates Cell D6 with the letter "X"
def itemRow(sheet):
    searchColA = "Apple"
    searchColB = "Red"
    row = [i+1 for i, r in enumerate(sheet.get_all_values()) if 
           r[0] == searchColA and r[1] == searchColB][0]
    sheet.update("D" + str(row), "X")
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I followed the response of Tanaike (below) and was able to enter any combination of A and B, and the code will output the corresponding row number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I saw the document of `find` of gspread, it says `in_column (int) – (optional) One-based column number to scope the search.`. In this case, unfortunately, it seems that only one column is used for searching values. And, when I saw the script of gspread, in the case of `find` method, it seems that a value is searched by retrieving all values from the sheet. [Ref](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/d576078d9ed246fc85f879b94f9d3c16d54f64c9/gspread/worksheet.py#L2043) When `find` is used 2 times, your goal can be achieved. But, in this case, 2 API calls are required. So, I thought that in your situation, when the above flow is reflected for achieving your goal, your goal can be achieved by one API call. In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```py
client = ### # Please use your client.

searchColA = "Apple" # This is used for searching column "A".
searchColB = "Red" # This is used for searching column "B".
spreadsheetId = "###" # Please set your spreadsheet ID.
sheetName = "Sheet1" # Please set your sheet name.

spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)
sheet = spreadsheet.worksheet(sheetName)
res = [i + 1 for i, r in enumerate(sheet.get_all_values()) if r[0] == searchColA and r[1] == searchColB]

print(res) # Found row numbers. In this case, 1st row number is 1.
```

#### Reference:

- [find(query, in_row=None, in_column=None, case_sensitive=True)](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.7.0/api/models/worksheet.html#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.find)

Comment: Thanks, this worked! For `searchColA` and `searchColB`, I'm able to enter any combination of fruit and color and it outputs the corresponding row number.

Comment: @RCube123 About `Thanks, this worked! For searchColA and searchColB, I'm able to enter any combination of fruit and color and it outputs the corresponding row number. `, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer